# AWS CodePipeline Running .NET core Unit Tests - Could not resolve this reference

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, asp.net-core, nuget, xcodebuild

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 app that I'm currently running in CodeBuild in AWS. I'm using Docker containers with the latest Microsoft SDK. I have some unit tests that I'd like to validate before it proceeds in the pipeline (Continuous Integration).

I'm getting stuck in running `dotnet test`: I'm getting hit by a `Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores - Could not resolve this reference.` error. (See logs down below).

This should be a simple fix, as it would only need to install the aforementioned package, but I can't find how to install it or how to force the dependencies to get it installed.

I've tried a lot of stuff:

- Checking individually each .csproj to see if it needs any additional reference.

  - Manually installing the pacakge via NuGet in Visual Studio 2017.
  - Running `dotnet clean` `dotnet restore`, I've even tried adding it manually (but then I get another error, that dotnet add doesnt' support adding that type of package).
  - I've tried forcing the installation of the packages, and nothing.

I've also tried searching where the NuGet Package manager is finding all of the dependencies, so I could potentially generate a NuGet.config file and implicitly include the dependency mentioned. But I haven't nailed such location (if it exists).

Any ideas?

---

Here's the full log (Failure is among the last lines):

```
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:13 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:15 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:23 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:23 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:23 YAML location is /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/buildspec.yml
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:23 Processing environment variables
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:23 Moving to directory /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:23 Registering with agent
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:23 Phases found in YAML: 2
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:23 PRE_BUILD: 1 commands
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:23 BUILD: 1 commands
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:23 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE Success: true
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:23 Phase context status code: Message:
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:23 Entering phase INSTALL
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:23 Phase complete: INSTALL Success: true
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:23 Phase context status code: Message:
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:23 Entering phase PRE_BUILD
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:23 Running command dotnet restore EducacionDanielWeb.sln
 Restoring packages for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/Common/Common.csproj...
 Restoring packages for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EFRepository/EduPlaTools.Persistence.csproj...
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions 2.0.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Options 2.0.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 2.0.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.0.0.
 Installing System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 4.4.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Options 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 2.0.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 2.0.0.
 Installing System.ComponentModel.Annotations 4.4.0.
 Installing System.Security.Cryptography.Cng 4.4.0.
 Installing System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 4.5.0.
 Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies 2.2.0.
 Installing AWSSDK.EC2 3.3.76.1.
 Installing AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2 3.3.15.3.
 Installing Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 2.1.4.
 Installing System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData 4.5.0.
 Installing Castle.Core 4.2.1.
 Installing AWSSDK.Core 3.3.29.14.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 2.0.0.
 Installing AWSSDK.Core 3.3.29.15.
 Installing System.Collections.Immutable 1.4.0.
 Installing Remotion.Linq 2.1.1.
 Installing System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 4.4.1.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 2.0.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 2.1.1.
 Installing AutoMapper 8.0.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 2.1.1.
 Installing System.Interactive.Async 3.1.1.
 Installing Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore 1.8.18.
 Installing Pomelo.JsonObject 2.0.0.
 Installing MySqlConnector 0.47.1.
 Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.1.4.
 Installing System.Diagnostics.TraceSource 4.3.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 2.1.1.
 Installing System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 4.5.1.
 Installing System.Threading.Thread 4.0.0.
 Installing System.Net.Requests 4.0.11.
 Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers 2.1.4.
 Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.0.0.
 Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions 2.1.4.
 Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.0.
 Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.4.
 Installing System.Net.WebHeaderCollection 4.0.1.
 Installing Microsoft.CSharp 4.4.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 2.0.0.
 Installing System.Buffers 4.4.0.
 Installing System.Memory 4.5.0.
 Installing System.Numerics.Vectors 4.4.0.
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EFRepository/obj/EduPlaTools.Persistence.csproj.nuget.g.props.
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/Common/obj/Common.csproj.nuget.g.props.
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EFRepository/obj/EduPlaTools.Persistence.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/Common/obj/Common.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
 Restore completed in 5.66 sec for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EFRepository/EduPlaTools.Persistence.csproj.
 Restore completed in 5.66 sec for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/Common/Common.csproj.
 Restoring packages for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Commands/EduPlaTools.Commands.csproj...
 Restoring packages for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Data.Common/EduPlaTools.Data.Common.csproj...
 Installing MediatR 6.0.0.
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Commands/obj/EduPlaTools.Commands.csproj.nuget.g.props.
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Commands/obj/EduPlaTools.Commands.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
 Restore completed in 246.25 ms for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Commands/EduPlaTools.Commands.csproj.
 Restoring packages for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Domain/EduPlaTools.Domain.csproj...
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Data.Common/obj/EduPlaTools.Data.Common.csproj.nuget.g.props.
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Data.Common/obj/EduPlaTools.Data.Common.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
 Restore completed in 293.33 ms for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Data.Common/EduPlaTools.Data.Common.csproj.
 Restoring packages for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.General.UnitTest/EduPlaTools.General.UnitTest.csproj...
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Domain/obj/EduPlaTools.Domain.csproj.nuget.g.props.
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Domain/obj/EduPlaTools.Domain.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
 Restore completed in 53.04 ms for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Domain/EduPlaTools.Domain.csproj.
 Restoring packages for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Query.UnitTest/EduPlaTools.Query.UnitTest.csproj...
 Installing System.Collections.Specialized 4.0.1.
 Installing System.Collections.NonGeneric 4.0.1.
 Installing System.ComponentModel.Primitives 4.1.0.
 Installing System.ComponentModel 4.0.1.
 Installing System.Xml.XPath 4.0.1.
 Installing Microsoft.Win32.Registry 4.0.0.
 Installing System.Threading.ThreadPool 4.0.10.
 Installing System.Collections.Immutable 1.2.0.
 Installing System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter 4.1.0.
 Installing System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument 4.0.1.
 Installing System.Diagnostics.Process 4.1.0.
 Installing System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync 4.0.11.
 Installing System.Diagnostics.TraceSource 4.0.0.
 Installing System.Reflection.Metadata 1.3.0.
 Installing System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener 4.0.0.
 Installing System.Runtime.Loader 4.0.0.
 Installing xunit.runner.visualstudio 2.4.1.
 Installing Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions 1.0.3.
 Installing xunit.abstractions 2.0.3.
 Installing xunit 2.4.1.
 Installing Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 15.9.0.
 Installing Shouldly 3.0.2.
 Installing Microsoft.TestPlatform.ObjectModel 15.9.0.
 Installing xunit.assert 2.4.1.
 Installing xunit.analyzers 0.10.0.
 Installing xunit.core 2.4.1.
 Installing Microsoft.CodeCoverage 15.9.0.
 Installing Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHost 15.9.0.
 Installing xunit.extensibility.execution 2.4.1.
 Installing xunit.extensibility.core 2.4.1.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 1.0.3.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions 2.1.0.
 Installing AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 6.0.0.
 Installing MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 6.0.1.
 Installing AWSSDK.SecretsManager 3.3.2.30.
 Installing Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities 2.1.1.
 Installing bootstrap 4.1.3.
 Installing Sendgrid 9.10.0.
 Installing AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup 3.3.6.
 Installing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets 1.1.1.
 Installing BenchmarkDotNet.Core 0.10.14.
 Installing AWS.Logger.AspNetCore 1.4.1.
 Installing Localization.AspNetCore.TagHelpers 0.5.0.
 Installing FluentValidation.AspNetCore 8.1.1.
 Installing ElectronNET.API 0.0.10.
 Installing popper.js 1.14.0.
 Installing jQuery 3.0.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions 1.1.2.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 1.0.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 1.0.2.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 1.0.2.
 Installing AWSSDK.Core 3.3.13.3.
 Installing System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument 4.3.0.
 Installing Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions 1.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions 1.0.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 1.0.0.
 Installing AWS.Logger.Core 1.3.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime 2.1.2.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization 2.1.3.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy 2.1.1.
 Installing FluentValidation 8.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions 2.1.1.
 Installing SocketIoClientDotNet 1.0.5.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 1.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features 1.1.2.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 1.0.1.
 Installing System.Linq.Expressions 4.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 1.0.0.
 Installing AWSSDK.CloudWatchLogs 3.3.4.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor 2.1.2.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Localization 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor 2.1.3.
 Installing System.ComponentModel.Annotations 4.4.1.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions 2.1.3.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions 2.1.1.
 Installing WebSocket4Net 0.15.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing 2.1.1.
 Installing SuperSocket.ClientEngine.Core 0.9.0.
 Installing EngineIoClientDotNet 1.0.5.
 Installing System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 4.3.0.
 Installing AWSSDK.Core 3.3.17.
 Installing System.Net.WebSockets 4.3.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures 2.1.3.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Abstractions 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Options 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Localization 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions 2.1.0.
 Installing System.Net.WebHeaderCollection 4.3.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection 2.1.0.
 Installing System.Net.Requests 4.3.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations 2.1.3.
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Query.UnitTest/obj/EduPlaTools.Query.UnitTest.csproj.nuget.g.props.
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Query.UnitTest/obj/EduPlaTools.Query.UnitTest.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
 Restore completed in 2.08 sec for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Query.UnitTest/EduPlaTools.Query.UnitTest.csproj.
 Restoring packages for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Query/EduPlaTools.Query.csproj...
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json 2.1.3.
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Query/obj/EduPlaTools.Query.csproj.nuget.g.props.
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Query/obj/EduPlaTools.Query.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
 Restore completed in 96.34 ms for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Query/EduPlaTools.Query.csproj.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 2.1.3.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery 2.1.1.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Abstractions 2.1.0.
 Restoring packages for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaToolsNoSQLRepo/EduPlaToolsNoSQLRepo.csproj...
 Installing System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.5.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 2.1.0.
 Installing Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool 2.1.0.
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaToolsNoSQLRepo/obj/EduPlaToolsNoSQLRepo.csproj.nuget.g.props.
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaToolsNoSQLRepo/obj/EduPlaToolsNoSQLRepo.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
 Restore completed in 1.45 sec for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaToolsNoSQLRepo/EduPlaToolsNoSQLRepo.csproj.
 Restoring packages for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EducacionDanielWeb/EduPlaToolsWeb.csproj...
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.General.UnitTest/obj/EduPlaTools.General.UnitTest.csproj.nuget.g.props.
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.General.UnitTest/obj/EduPlaTools.General.UnitTest.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
 Restore completed in 4.09 sec for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.General.UnitTest/EduPlaTools.General.UnitTest.csproj.
 Restoring packages for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/Utilities/Utilities.csproj...
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/Utilities/obj/Utilities.csproj.nuget.g.props.
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/Utilities/obj/Utilities.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
 Restore completed in 2.83 ms for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/Utilities/Utilities.csproj.
 Installing System.Composition.Convention 1.0.31.
 Installing System.Composition.Runtime 1.0.31.
 Installing System.Composition.TypedParts 1.0.31.
 Installing System.Composition.AttributedModel 1.0.31.
 Installing System.Composition.Hosting 1.0.31.
 Installing System.Composition 1.0.31.
 Installing System.Linq.Parallel 4.3.0.
 Installing Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common 2.8.0.
 Installing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 2.2.0.
 Installing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.2.0.
 Installing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration 2.2.0.
 Installing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.0.
 Installing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core 2.2.0.
 Installing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Templating 2.2.0.
 Installing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils 2.2.0.
 Installing Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces 2.8.0.
 Installing NuGet.Frameworks 4.7.0.
 Installing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Contracts 2.2.0.
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EducacionDanielWeb/obj/EduPlaToolsWeb.csproj.nuget.g.props.
 Generating MSBuild file /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EducacionDanielWeb/obj/EduPlaToolsWeb.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
 Restore completed in 3.7 sec for /codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EducacionDanielWeb/EduPlaToolsWeb.csproj.
 [Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:39 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD Success: true
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:39 Phase context status code: Message:
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:39 Entering phase BUILD
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:39 Running command dotnet test EduPlaTools.General.UnitTest/EduPlaTools.General.UnitTest.csproj --configuration release
Build started, please wait...
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.100/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [/codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Data.Common/EduPlaTools.Data.Common.csproj]
ApplicationUser.cs(4,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Data.Common/EduPlaTools.Data.Common.csproj]
ApplicationUser.cs(9,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityUser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/codebuild/output/src005625819/src/git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduplatoolsweb/EduPlaTools.Data.Common/EduPlaTools.Data.Common.csproj]
 [Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:45 Command did not exit successfully dotnet test EduPlaTools.General.UnitTest/EduPlaTools.General.UnitTest.csproj --configuration release exit status 1
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:45 Phase complete: BUILD Success: false
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:45 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: dotnet test EduPlaTools.General.UnitTest/EduPlaTools.General.UnitTest.csproj --configuration release. Reason: exit status 1
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:45 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:45 Phase complete: POST_BUILD Success: true
[Container] 2018/12/15 16:26:45 Phase context status code: Message:
```

Here's a picture:

[image]

Here's the buildspec.yml file that I have:
    version: 0.2

```
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html
phases:
    pre_build:
        commands:
            - dotnet restore EducacionDanielWeb.sln
    build:
        commands:
            - dotnet test EduPlaTools.General.UnitTest/EduPlaTools.General.UnitTest.csproj
cache:
    paths:
        - '~/.nuget/packages'
```

Here's the Docker image configuration that I'm currently using:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

FOUND IT!!!!!

So the problem was with the references **inside** each of the .csproj files

```
<Reference Include="Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore">
      <HintPath>C:\Users\asili\.nuget\packages\z.entityframework.plus.efcore\1.8.18\lib\netstandard2.0\Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

I had to remove the `<HintPath>` from each of the references. Apparently, they were referencing my local NuGet package location.

Deleting them solved all of the problems!!!!!!

Comment: When I created a Class Library that references class objects that are from an implicitly installed library in the dotnet project, this <HintPath> thing autogenerated for me. Not sure when, or why(It might be a Rider thing). This specifically happened to me when I had one of my models in my shared(Class Library in Blazor Webassembly) project inherit IdentityUser.  If anyone is in a similar circumstance they need to delete the <HintPath> as described in answer and then explicitly install Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores